# numpy einsum collapse all but first dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-einsum

I have an array of dimension `(5,...)` (`...` can be anything) and I would like to form the dot product of all dimension after the `5` such that the resulting array has shape `(5,)`. I thought the einsum

```
i...,i...->i
```

looked promising, but alas

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(5)
b = np.einsum("i...,i...->i", a, a)
assert b.shape == (5,)  # okay


a = np.random.rand(5, 2)
b = np.einsum("i...,i...->i", a, a)  # fail
assert b.shape == (5,)


a = np.random.rand(5, 2, 3)
b = np.einsum("i...,i...->i", a, a)  # fail
assert b.shape == (5,)
```

```
in einsum
    return c_einsum(*operands, **kwargs)
ValueError: output has more dimensions than subscripts given in einstein sum, but no '...' ellipsis provided to broadcast the extra dimensions.
```

I could perhaps reshape `a` into

```py
b = np.einsum("ij,ij->i", a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1), a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1))
```

but this looks so messy. Any better suggestion?

Comment: I was thinking that `np.tensordot(x,x,axes=([1,2,3],[1,2,3])` would do it, but for a (5,3,3,3) shape, it produces a (5,5) output.  Can that then be summed?

Comment: `x = a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1); np.einsum("ij,ij->i", x,x)` looks good to me. Aslo `(a*a).reshape(a.shape[0],-1).sum(-1)` would work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, ellipsis "enable and control broadcasting". You want to do the dot sum-of-products on these dimensions. Those dimensions require explicit entires. So for a 4d with reduction on the last 2 dimensions, '...ij->...'

```
In [15]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
```

reduction on last or last 2 dimensions:

```
In [17]: np.einsum('...i->...',arr).shape
Out[17]: (2, 3)
In [18]: np.einsum('...ij->...',arr).shape
Out[18]: (2,)
```

`sum` equivalents:

```
In [20]: arr.sum(axis=(-1))
Out[20]: 
array([[ 6, 22, 38],
       [54, 70, 86]])
In [21]: arr.sum(axis=(-1)).shape
Out[21]: (2, 3)
In [22]: arr.sum(axis=(-2,-1)).shape
Out[22]: (2,)
In [23]: arr.sum(axis=(-2,-1))
Out[23]: array([ 66, 210])
In [24]: np.einsum('...ij->...',arr)
Out[24]: array([ 66, 210])
```

This expression from `sympy` may help visualize `einsum`

```
In [37]: f = Function('f')
    ...: Sum(f(x,y,z), (y, 0, 3),(z,0,2))
Out[37]: 
  2     3             
 ___   ___            
 ╲     ╲              
  ╲     ╲             
  ╱     ╱   f(x, y, z)
 ╱     ╱              
 ‾‾‾   ‾‾‾            
z = 0 y = 0
```

`f` is function of 3 variables (3d).  `einsum` notation emulates Einstein notation, where dimensions that should be summed are explicitly listed.  Ones that aren't summed, that in a sense, are just carried along, don't need to be (as) explicit.

Answer (score 0):

For illustration, assume tensor A is a 2-by-2 matrix. The dot-product you need can be written as

C_i = A_{kj} A_{ij} D_{ki},

where D is the identity matrix.

Using `np.einsum`, this can be written as

```
D= np.identity(2)
X= np.einsum("k...,i...,ki->i...", A, A, D)
C= np.sum(X.reshape(X.shape[0],-1),axis=-1)
```

We need `np.sum` in the above to sum over all j indices.

Comment: "kj,ij,ki->i" would sum over `j` directly.

Comment: Yes but that requires us to manually enter indices for all dimensions and hence not generalizable. The code for a 2x2x3 matrix, for example, will be different from that for a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: But the `sum` still nneds the axes.

Comment: You are right. I updated the answer to generalize it by flattening the array and summing over the first dimension

Comment: I think with this modification my solution looks less elegant than the one posted in the question